# Debian ARM on chroot Mumble server error

Tags: chroot, arm, voip

I use Debian running in a chroot next Android.

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.0.64-CM-g7e7a10d #5 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 8 17:34:47 BRT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I installed mumble server

```
apt-get install mumble
```

I checked if it works

```
ps -ef | grep mumble
111       6556     1  0 12:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/murmurd -ini /etc/mumble-server.ini
```

But I can not connect to it. I checked whether the server is listening.

```
netstat -nlp | grep mum
```

Gets empty result. I installed the server on Fedora x64 and it works fine. 
I don't know why mumble server do not want to operate on a system of arm.

Next,I began to compile the source

```
qmake main.pro
make
```

I get an error

```
    g++ -pipe -Wfatal-errors -fvisibility=hidden -Wshadow -Woverloaded-
virtual -Wold-style-cast -Wconversion -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wextra -I../../speex/include -I../../speexbuild -O2 -I../../speex/include -I../../speexbuild -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DRESTRICT=__restrict__ -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DMUMBLE_VERSION_STRING=1.2.8 -DMUMBLE -DNO_CRASH_REPORT -DUSE_OPUS -DUSE_ALSA -DUSE_OSS -DUSE_BONJOUR -DUSE_DBUS -DUSE_SPEECHD -DUSE_G15 -DUSING_BUNDLED_QT_TRANSLATIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_DBUS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../src -I. -I../bonjour -I../../speex/include -I../../speex/libspeex -I../../speexbuild -I../../celt-0.7.0-src/libcelt -I../../opus-src/celt -I../../opus-src/include -I../../opus-src/src -I../../opus-build/src -I/usr/lib/oss/include -isystem /usr/include/alsa -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtSvg -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtDBus -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtCore -Irelease -I. -x c++-header -c mumble_pch.hpp -o release/mumble.gch/c++
    mumble_pch.hpp:65:27: fatal error: boost/array.hpp: No such file or directory
     #include <boost/array.hpp>
                               ^
    compilation terminated.
    Makefile.Release:557: recipe for target 'release/mumble.gch/c++' failed
    make[2]: *** [release/mumble.gch/c++] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/mumble-1.2.8/src/mumble'
    Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
    make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/mumble-1.2.8/src/mumble'
    Makefile:217: recipe for target 'sub-src-mumble-make_first-ordered' failed
    make: *** [sub-src-mumble-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

Would you recommend any other VOIP server that I could run on ARM system?

murmurd log:

```
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.649 Initializing settings from /etc/mumble-server.ini (basepath /etc)
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.652 OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
<C>2015-05-05 13:39:04.653 Successfully switched to uid 111
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.904 ServerDB: Opened SQLite database /var/lib/mumble-server/mumble-server.sqlite
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.910 Resource limits were 0 0
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.911 Successfully dropped capabilities
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.919 Failed to register on DBus:  
<C>2015-05-05 13:39:04.946 MurmurIce: Initialization failed: Ice::SocketException
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.950 OSInfo: Failed to execute lsb_release
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:04.950 Murmur 1.2.8 (1.2.8-2) running on X11: Linux 3.0.64-CM-g7e7a10d: Booting servers
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:05.050 1 => Announcing server via bonjour
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:05.119 1 => Not registering server as public
<W>2015-05-05 13:39:05.119 Object::connect: No such slot MurmurDBus::userTextMessage(const User *, const TextMessage &)
```

Comment: Try installing the following package and run it again;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241152/boost-no-such-file-or-directory